# Disable React.createClass and PropTypes deprecated warnings in babel react present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

At latest React 15.5.1 package, If using babel react present to resolve jsx file, will appears following warnings:

```
Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

warning.js:36 Warning: A Component: React.createClass is deprecated and will be removed in version 16. Use plain JavaScript classes instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class is available on npm as a drop-in replacement.
```

My code is following:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 1
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval( ()=> {
      this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
        count: prevState.count + 1
      }))
    }, 1000)
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
    )
  }
}

const root = document.createElement('div');
root.id = 'app';
document.body.appendChild(root);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

I am not using React.createClass and PropTypes in my code, It seems babel transform my code to `React.createClass` and `PropTypes`, How to fix that?

Comment: Are you sure it's coming from this code? babeljs.io doesn't seem to think so; [this gist shows your source and the babeljs output](https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/495104605f24c588624f5b169075c091). Check it out at https://babeljs.io/repl. What version of Babel are you using?

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same issue with newly installed npm packages. I guess it might be a result of some breaking changes???

Comment: would be nice if deprecation warnings were yellow instead of red in the dev console.

Answer (score 12):

React 15.5.0 contain new warnings belong to the changes that are coming on React 16, the warning that you are getting, is actually telling you that you have to implement the new way (since the current way that you are using is going to be deprecated on 16).

`React.createClass`, you have 2 options, first one is to just use plain  JS syntax:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

or use the `create-react-class` module (availiable on npm):

```
// Before (15.4 and below)
var React = require('react');

var Component = React.createClass({
  mixins: [MixinA],
  render() {
    return <Child />;
  }
});

// After (15.5)
var React = require('react');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var Component = createReactClass({
  mixins: [MixinA],
  render() {
    return <Child />;
  }
});
```

About the PropTypes warning, check if you are using module that using PropTypes, sometimes it's coming from external part.

Anyway, to read more about it, you are welcome to get [Facebook blog post about those changes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html)

Comment: You can also use es6 classes to define components

Comment: Best answer as this is spot on with the suggestion in dev tools console. Accessing createClass via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in React v16.0. Use a plain JavaScript class instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class v15.* is available on npm as a temporary, drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 5):

React **v15.5.0** implements [new warnings](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html)

Downgrading React to **15.4.x** works for me

```
npm install --save react@15.4.0 react-dom@15.4.0
```

Comment: incredible, by updating to the new version 5 error-warnings have gone..

Comment: @eugen_sunic - version 5 of what? what did you update?

Comment: The react dom package.. It's not version 5, I'm saying that it removed 5 errors

Answer (score 4):

`React.createClass` and `React.PropTypes` has been deprecated in v15.5.

Some Peers/dependencies must be  using `React.createClass` and `React.PropTypes` with `React:^15.4` (or any other version), which is very much compatible with your react version.
So getting Warning for there code.

Please refer [this link](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html)  for 15.5 Changes

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html

Answer (score 4):

I found that the warning was present because I was importing React with

```
import * as React from 'react'
```

changing this to

```
import React from 'react'
```

makes the warnings disappear

Comment: when using Flow the other imports are necessary. here's a  different workaround for Jest: https://gist.github.com/turadg/9bcf08a7279e82a030a645250639fe6e

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just one more thing to add, as I can not yet comment :-( Maybe someone else have same issue with react-bootstrap

I got the same when using react-bootstrap 0.30.8 together with react 15.5.3.

Warning: Uncontrolled(Dropdown): React.createClass is deprecated and will be removed in version 16. Use plain JavaScript classes instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class is available on npm as a drop-in replacement.

I get in:
uncontrollable/createUncontrollable.js --->

```
var component = _react2.default.createClass(_extends({
```

uncontrollable@4.0.3 is a dep of react-bootstrap 0.30.8

and

Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.

react-bootstrap/es/PanelGroup.js --->

```
accordion: React.PropTypes.bool
```

I think downgrading react is the only way to workaround here, as react-bootstrap is not yet far enough.

Answer (score -4):

You should not be extending react.Component. You need to import Component from react and extend it has shown here:

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';

  class Counter extends Component{
  //your code here
  render (){

    return (
       <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
    );
   }
}
```

You can read about the differences and ES6 classes [here](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/)

Comment: Can you explain bit more about `class MyComponent extends React.Component` vs `class MyComponent extends Component`? @N. Solomon

Comment: @SiddharthTrivedi - you can use Component if you import it with react. Ex: `import React, { Component } from 'react';`

Comment: you are just basically extracting Component from the react, since React.Component is also correct.